# Using AVERAGEIF, how do I exclude Zeros?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The current AverageIf forumla works well for me. But the problem is it's counting all the Zero's in my data. Are you able to provide guidance on how i add into this formula the exclusion of Zero's?

`=AVERAGEIF('YTD PPV - 410'!$A:$A,'Aus - YTD @ Standard'!$B$54&'Aus - YTD @ Standard'!B55,'YTD PPV - 410'!$P:$P)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AVERAGEIFS()` to set multiple IF criteria.

Are your zeroes in column A or P? Assuming they're in column P you could use this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS( P:P      <-- column with values you want to average
            ,A:A      <-- column to match your first criteria against
            ,B54&B55  <-- your first criteria
            ,P:P      <-- column to match your second criteria against
            ,"<>0"    <-- your second criteria
           )
```

adding your sheetnames back in, we have:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('YTD PPV - 410'!$P:$P,'YTD PPV - 410'!$A:$A,'Aus - YTD @ Standard'!$B$54&'Aus - YTD @ Standard'!B55,'YTD PPV - 410'!$P:$P,"<>0")
```